# MariaDB won't work after reboot

Tags: server, mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to get mariadb 10.3 to work on a fresh installation of ubuntu server 16.04 which comes with mysql 5.7 so I've started by stopping and removing it using

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-server
```

and then installed trough the official repo mariadb-server, after than I ran:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
sudo mysql_upgrade
```

and everything seemed to work just fine but as soon as I rebooted my VM it won't start anymore echoing this error:

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details
```

systemctl:

```
[Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
[Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown
[Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
[Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 3082519; transaction id 1362
[Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file "ibtmp1"
[Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Failed to start MariaDB 10.0.3.14 database server.
mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

journalctl:

```
ubuntu systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
ubuntu sudo[1432]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
ubuntu systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

I've tried some "solutions" found on the web like changing ownership and/or permissions to /var/lib/mysql folder or adding some my.cnf config lines but nothing worked.

Any idea?

Comment: Do the supplied commands `systemctl status mariadb.service` and `journalctl -xe` give more information about the problem? If so, add this to your question.

Comment: Yeah, you will need to include the journal log for mariadb in your question

Comment: systemctl was already there. Added the journalctl -xe result :)